# how to get 0 or 1 in mysql according to a boolean?

Tags: java, jdbc, boolean

I have a Boolean in a Java class and want to use this status for inserting 0 or 1 status in Mysql database. When I am getting data from the database, it always returns true [1 in database].

Can anyone tell me how to get 0 or 1 in database according to the boolean.

```
boolean status= Boolean.parseBoolean(parameterStatus);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `status ? 1 : 0`

Comment: Make sure to select best answer

Comment: Thank you @user7294900 it helped

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear to what you are asking. What I think you meant is "why is the database always returning 1 (for true) when doing a query?".

This could be because you are always inserting a 1 (true).

Here is an example of how to insert and get a boolean into a database.

```
try{  
            // create a mysql database connection
            String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

            // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            // the mysql insert statement
            String query = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString (1, "Barney");
            preparedStmt.setString (2, "Rubble");
            preparedStmt.setDate   (3, startDate);
            preparedStmt.setBoolean(4, false);
            preparedStmt.setInt    (5, 5000);

            // execute the preparedstatement
            preparedStmt.execute();




            //now to get the boolean from Database
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
            while(rs.next())  
                System.out.println(rs.getBoolean(4));  
            conn.close();  


        }catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```